# Allow Positive Value in TcxDBcurrencyEdit

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I'm using Delphi 7 and dev express
I add tcxDBcurrency to my Form, in the object inspector 
in DisplayFormat I put : ,0.000; (to allow only positiv value )
but when I m testing my component when I try to put '-' I have an exception , 
I have a solution that on presskey I disallow the insert of '-' 
here are another solution please , I think I have a probleme in my DisplayFormat?

Comment: "I have an exception." You can it, and the message. We cannot.

Comment: the probleme that U delete the negative value in displayFormat, I didn't understand why I have the possibility to insert'-'?

Comment: " I didn't understand why I have the possibility to insert'-' "  Err, to allow the user to enter a negative amount, a debit instead of a credit in a n account or whatever.

Comment: so to dessallow the insert of '-' we must delete it in the onkeyPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This DevEx support post](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q214261) suggests two solutions:

1. Add on OnKeyPress handler to your editor, and suppress the '-'
2. Set the MinValue to 0. This will let the user enter the '-'but on Exit will trigger the validation routines.

It also looks as if you are confusing DisplayFormat and EditFormat.

Comment: I Add OnKeyPress handler to suppress the '-' the second solution , didin't resolve my probleme